# Android drag and drop between different canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drag-and-drop, android-fragments

I have two fragments. Each fragment contains canvas. Both fragments are visible on the screen at the same time.

On first canvas I have some images, which I placed there dynamically. I need to drag selected image from first canvas and drop it to the second canvas.

I couldn't find any examples on the web how to do that. I found only example how to drag and drop Views. But in my case it seems like it's impossible replace canvas with view.